# How to handle geometry change in vector layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I'm building a plugin in Python that manage some lists of WKT from different intern sources (web services, bd, etc..). I can display every source without any problem.

For displaying them, I use a QVectorLayer of type "memory" (in QGIS 1.7.4 by the way).

I would like the user to be able to edit a feature (the geometry) when it's possible, and I would change the value according to the source.

So I was very interested by:

```
void QgsVectorLayer::geometryChanged(QgsFeatureId fid, QgsGeometry &geom)
```

[Doc is here](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#d64d9c5712cfb2363b2ee9421dbf9ad2)

But when I write this:

```
layer.geometryChanged.connect(self._geometryChanged)
[...]
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def _geometryChanged(self, fid, geom):
    [...]
```

I've got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryChanged'
```

Any idea How I could do it?

Is there any better documentation about inner elements in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find it because it doesn't exist in the 1.7.4 python bindings.

The geometryChanged signal was added at commit [9f4996fc210eaa8c2495c912bc7214d37256ea63](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/9f4996fc210eaa8c2495c912bc7214d37256ea63) on Jan 13th 2012

You only option in order to use this signal is to upgrade to the latest build.

Comment: Thanks you very much.
I will try do to it an other way...